# Error while adding MySql Plugin

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, mysql5.7

OS- Ubuntu 16.04

Mysql Version- 5.7

Getting error while installing plugin into Mysql ex.

```
INSTALL PLUGIN QUERY_RESPONSE_TIME_AUDIT SONAME 'query_response_time.so';
```

check plugin directory

```
show variables like 'plugin_dir';
```

And its showing `/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/`
But **query_response_time.so** file not present there. i have tired with percona server and all plugin available but not with MySql.

How can i get this file and fix this error for mysql 5.7 ?